# how to remove all elements from a table row except first th

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table row like this

This row is generated using a for loop in jquery ,there can be more than 1 row .I want to remove all elements except first of each row ,I have tried like this

```js
for (var i = 0; i < o.result[0].length; i++) {
  //$("#fullSelection"+i).empty(); //its working
  //$("#fullSelection"+i).not(':first').remove();//not working
  $("#fullSelection" + i).slice(1).remove(); //not working
}
```

```html
<tr id='fullSelection0' style='display: table-row;'>
  <th class='predict'>

  </th>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Any idea how to achieve it??

Comment: `$("#fullSelection" + i).find('td').remove();` the real question is why are you combining `th` with `td`?

Comment: grad it works happy coding

Answer (score 1):

An HTML table has two kinds of cells:

**Header cells** - contains header information (created with the `<th>` element)

**Standard cells** - contains data (created with the `<td>` element)

In HTML table design, you should not combine both *th* and *td* inside the same *tr*.

I think you do not need the looping for that. You can simply target and remove all the children except the first in each `tr` with jQuery selector like:

```js
$('tr td,th').not(':first-child').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='fullSelection0' style='display: table-row;'>
    <th class='predict'>Col-Test</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id='fullSelection1' style='display: table-row;'>
    <th class='predict'>Col-Test2</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pure css using `not` & `:first--child`

```css
tr>td:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id='fullSelection0' style='display: table-row;'>
    <th class='predict'>Col-Test</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id='fullSelection1' style='display: table-row;'>
    <th class='predict'>Col-Test2</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way.

```js
$("tr > td:not(:first-child)").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='fullSelection0' style='display: table-row;'>
    <th class='predict'>Col-Test</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id='fullSelection1' style='display: table-row;'>
    <th class='predict'>Col-Test2</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```